# jquery css change causes typeError is null

Tags: jquery, css, forms

Hey all i am wondering why i am getting this error with the following code:

The javascript:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://max.jotfor.ms/min/g=jotform?3.0.3359" type="text/javascript"></script>

 function checkInput() {
if ($("#input_3") === null) {
    $('#error1').css('display', 'block');
        $('#error1').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
 ....
```

The CSS:

```
 .ErrorBlock1 {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;     
    background-color:#F00;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
 }
```

the HTML:

```
 <div id="cid_3" class="form-input-wide">
    <input name="q3_firstName3" type="text" class="form-textbox validate[required, Alphabetic]" id="input_3" size="25" style="width: 265px; height: 25px; background: transparent url(textfield.png) no-repeat center center; border: none;" onBlur="checkInput();" />
 <div class="ErrorBlock1" id="error1">First Name Req.</div>
 </div>
```

I am getting this error when running it:

```
Timestamp: 9/17/2012 9:10:15 AM
Error: TypeError: $("#error1") is null
```

Why am i getting this???

Comment: `display: visible` is invalid CSS.

Comment: This means jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks. But still have the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('#input_3')` will never return null. It will always be a jQuery object.

Check for its existence with `$('#input_3').length != 0`.

Comment: Seems to be related to something with the JotForm JS... geerrr. When i take that js out it works.

Answer (score 2):

For you use both `display` and `visibility` :

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/umoliz/5/edit)*

CSS:

```
.ErrorBlock1 {
    display: none; 
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color:#F00;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
 }
```

jQUery:

```
function checkInput() {
  if ($("#input_3").val().length) {
      $('#error1').show().css({visibility:'visible'});
  }else{
      $('#error1').hide().css({visibility:'hidden'});
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting **Error: TypeError: $("#input_3") is null** with that.

Comment: `if ($("#input_3").val().length > 0) {

}`  is probably what he meant.

Comment: Seems to be related to something with the JotForm JS... geerrr. When i take that js out it works.

Comment: @roXon: Thanks for the demo there! It helped a lot!